# Storing multiplier variables in PHP session and using loop to show them all

Tags: php, session-variables

I want to save products to by storing order values that come from ORDER page and show them on CART Page. Here is both pages coding. Can anybody please help me in this? It's for wordpress theme.

ORDER Page

```
<?php
session_start();
/*
TEMPLATE NAME: Order Page
*/


$git_product_id = $_GET['git_product_id'];
$git_required = $_GET['git_required'];
$git_action = $_GET['git_action'];

if ($git_product_id != "" && $git_required != "" && $git_action != "" ){            
    ?>
        <form action="" method="POST" class="add-form">
            <label>
                <?php 

                    switch($git_required){

                        case "name" :
                            // showing Name
                            echo "Account Name:";
                        break; 

                        case "url" :
                            // showing url
                            echo "Web Url:";
                        break;

                    };
                ?>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="git_required" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="git_product_id" value="<?php echo $git_product_id; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="git_action" value="add" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="add-to-cart-button" />
        </form> 
    <?php

} else {

    echo "Sorry an error took place.";
}
```

?>

===========================================================

CART PAGE

```
<?php
session_start();
/*
TEMPLATE NAME: Cart Page
*/
```

?>

```
<?php
    $git_product_id = $_POST['git_product_id'];
    $git_required = $_POST['git_required'];
    $git_action = $_POST['git_action'];

    if ($git_product_id != "" && $git_action != "" ){

        switch($git_action){

            case "add" :
                // adding product
                    // checking first if the product is already added
                    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$git_product_id])){
                        echo "You have already added this product";                     
                    } else {
                        // I AM NOT SURE IF THIS CODING IS OKAY. PLEASE CHECK THIS
                        $_SESSION['cart'][$git_product_id] = array('product_id' => $git_product_id, 'git_required' => $git_required );
                    }
            break;

            case "remove":
                // removing product
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$git_product_id]);
            break;

            case "empty" :
                // empty cart
                unset($_SESSION['cart']); 
            break;              

        } 
    }
?>

<?php 

    if ($_SESSION['cart'] != ""):
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product => $qty) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php // I WANT TO SHOW HERE EACH PRODUCT ID and RESPECTIVE REQUIRED INFO ?>
                <?php // BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO IT ?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="git_product_id" value="<?php echo $product; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="git_required" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="git_action" value="remove" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Remove" />
                </form>
            </td>

        <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="git_product_id" value="<?php echo $product; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="git_required" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="git_action" value="empty" />
        <input type="submit" value="empty" />
    </form>
```

Comment: remove the single quotes around $product when you echo out the product details

Comment: You need to add more details to your post. - What is not working? Does it show anything or nothing at all? - Are there any errors being displayed? - Are you using an existing cart component? Adding the name would help people that are experienced with it help you out.

Comment: @youcantseeme: Please check the main posting. I have shared coding of both order page and cart page.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote `$_SESSION['cart']['$product']...` but instead you should have written `$_SESSION['cart'][$product]...` without the ' round $product...

Explanation: `'$product'` is not the value of $product but only the string *$product*:

```
$product = 5;
var_dump($product);       // -> int(5)
var_dump("$product");     // -> string(1) "5"
var_dump('$product');     // -> string(8) "$product"
```